# How to extract language from HTML using twig

Tags: html, css, twig

if you inspect the page you can see at the beginning of page html lang="en"

i want to get the value of lang to write

if lang= en
show this link

if lang=ch
show this link

Anyone know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript:

```
var lang=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].lang;
if(lang=="en"){
    console.log("I am english");
}
else if(lang=="ch"){
    console.log("I am chineese");
}
```

**Edit**

The twig solution:

```
{% if  app.request.locale =="ch" %}
    <p>I am chineese</p>
{% else %}
    <p>I am english</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any twig solution rather than java-script